# Shortest C \ C++ function to generate -1, 0 ,1

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix, c, c++

Let a function receive two integers `i` and `j` between `0` and `3`, it should return the value in position `(i,j)` in the following 2D array:

```
1, 0, -1, 0
1, 0, -1, 0
0, 1, 0, -1
0, -1, 0, 1
```

Shortest code in any variant of C / C++ wins.

Comment: Why limit this to C/C++?

Comment: probably because the author realizes it is 3-4 chars in golfscript, and wants to make the competition more fair

Comment: @Kendall Frey - Actually the true code golf contests are possible only when they target single language (or family of languages). Because there is no point to compete when someone is running on foot, someone is swimming, and others use helicopter.

Comment: @mniip - I do not think this is 3 or 4 characters. I think it is about best C/C++ solution minus length of `return` keyword ;)

Comment: @SergeyS Even if I agreed, the rest of the site does not. Language-specific questions are discouraged here.

Comment: By the way, do you had in mind some truth-table approach when proposing the question?

Comment: How is this unclear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 32

```
f(i,j){return~-(j+2-i*i/3&3)%2;}
```

Comment: A winner by three chars :)

Comment: `f(i,j){return-~-(i*i/3^j)%2;}` is 29. I found it by [running an exhaustive(ish) search](https://github.com/lynn/pysearch). I can't post it because the question is closed, so I'll put it here.

Answer (score 10):

## 40

```
f(i,j){return~-(2434352710>>8*i+2*j&3);}
```

A hackish **35** solution (xxd dump):

```
0000000: 6628 692c 6a29 7b72 6574 7572 6e7e 2d28  f(i,j){return~-(
0000010: 695b 2246 4619 9122 5d3e 3e32 2a6a 2633  i["FF.."]>>2*j&3
0000020: 293b 7d                                  );}
```

If proper octal escapes are used, it's the same **40** characters:

```
f(i,j){return~-(i["FF\31\221"]>>2*j&3);}
```

Comment: You can save 8 bytes by writing `f(int i,int j)` as `f(i,j)` (the arguments are `int` by default)

Comment: I see, i actually tried removing those ints, but somehow failed

Answer (score 10):

## C99, 34

```
f(i,j){return(i<3?1-j+i/2:j-2)%2;}
```

Comment: Also works in C89. And function text is 34 chars

Comment: I marked it C99 since C99 actually specifies the behavior of '%', whereas prior versions left it implementation-defined. And yeah, I was counting the newline. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 5):

## C, 29

I know this one seems kinda unfair but does it actually work for anyone? ^_^

```
f(i,j){j=("&&4+"[i]>>j)%3-1;}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! You should add your byte count to the post as this is a code golf question. Also, you may want to add a link to an interpreter so that others can test your solution, such as [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#)

Answer (score 4):

## 38

```
f(i,j){return(i/2+j+1)*(1-(i-j&2))%2;}
```

## 37

```
f(i,j){return(i/2+j+1)*-~-(i-j&2)%2;}
```

Comment: You can save 2 chars if you change `(1-(i-j&2))` to `~-(j&2-i)`

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it gives wrong results.(i-j&2) is actually ((i-j)&2) so your trick changes the logic here. or am i missing something?

Comment: oh, I kind of overlooked that, still can save 1 by replacing with `-~-(i-j&2)`

Comment: @mniip oh yes now it works, thx

Answer (score 3):

## C++, <del>70</del>, <del>45</del>, 44

```
f(i,j){return(j/2&i^~i&~j>>1)*~-(j-i&2)%2;}
```

The Karnaugh map approach, mixed with a bit of fsw's solution.

If A is (j>>1) and D is (i&1), the function should return "-~-(j-i&2)%2" (fsw's solution) multiplied by the Karnaugh map ~A~D + AD.

I feel there is a better solution for this using the Karnaugh map, but it's too late to think of it. Maybe tomorrow :)

Thanks for the comments, shaved off many chars.

Comment: you don't need most of the parentheses here: `((~(j>>1)&~(i&1)^j>>1&(i&1))&1)`  also you can move the `&1` into inside the left side of `^` : `(~(j>>1)&~(i&1)&1^j>>1&(i&1))`

Answer (score 2):

## C#

```
int f(int i,int j){return "2101210112101012"[i*4+j]-49;}
```

Comment: 4 spaces will make that code highlighted...

Comment: You can save one character by removing the space after `return`. But it's arguable whether C# can be considered a variant of C/C++, despite the name. It's *derived from C*, but so is Java.

Answer (score 2):

## 48

```
f(a,b){return 10308>>4*a+b&1?-1:43605>>4*a+b&1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 45

```
f(i,j){i=i+(j>1)*(7-2*j)&3;return i&1?0:1-i;}
```